# How do I find a replacement Seat Post Binder screw for CAAD8

Tags: repair

I was in my garage getting my bike ready for a ride, tightening up the seat post binder when I noticed it said 5NM on it so I decided to grab one of my cheap Harbor Freight torque wrenches from my automotive toolbox 2 feet away and I'm guessing that wasn't a great idea as the bolt wound up snapping.

Does anyone know the size of the screw? If I go to a local bike shop will they be able to sell me one? Do I need to know the exact year, size, anything about my bike other than make/model? Will I need a whole new seatbinder?

Comment: My car torque wrench doesn't go anything like as low as 5nm, which really isn't much. For the bike I use a torque screwdriver.

Comment: Your challenge now is to get the broken stub piece out without damaging the bike.  There's no shame in paying a LBS to do this - you could wreck your frame if its an integrated binder.

Comment: Are you sure you did not dial up kg/m on the torque wrench?

Comment: @chrish apparently neither does mine even though it has markings for it.

Comment: got the stub out easily lbs was able to him me up thanks for all the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thread is almost certainly M5x0.8, which is the most common small fastener size on bikes, and common on many other things. Any bike shop and fastener/industrial supply stores as well as any hardware store with metric bolts should have it. Seatpost clamps usually take a hex cap bolt but they different in what length they need and sometimes are particular about the fit of the shoulder. The simple thing in your position would be to use a flat screwdriver or a pick to work the snapped bolt out and just bring the rest of the clamp in when you go get a new one.

Model year type data for something like this isn't really how it's done on bikes.

Comment: And this is somewhere where I would be happy to use a standard bolt - as you've found it's most likely to fail when being done up, and the forces on the bolt in normal riding aren't high